# Heroku Spring Boot doesn't build Jar

Tags: java, spring, heroku, gradle, spring-boot

I am deploying to Heroku, I haven't really changed anything yet now Heroku is not creating the Jar.

Gradle buildpack is still in "beta" though it hasn't ever failed me.

Heroku

```
remote: -----> Using set buildpack heroku/gradle
remote: -----> Gradle app detected
remote: -----> Installing OpenJDK 1.8... done
remote: -----> Installing Gradle Wrapper...
remote:        WARNING: Your application does not have it's own gradlew file.
remote:        We'll install one for you, but this is a deprecated feature and
remote:        in the future may not be supported.
remote: -----> Building Gradle app...
remote:        WARNING: The Gradle buildpack is currently in Beta.
remote: -----> executing ./gradlew stage
remote:        :api:compileJavaNote: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
remote:        Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
remote:        
remote:        :api:processResources
remote:        :api:classes
remote:        :api:war
remote:        :api:bootRepackage
remote:        :api:assemble
remote:        :api:cleanNode
remote:        :api:stage
remote:        BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Notice the lack of `:api:jar` and yet locally it is there..

```
:api:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:api:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:api:classes UP-TO-DATE
:api:jar
:api:findMainClass
:api:startScripts
:api:distTar
:api:distZip
:api:war
:api:bootRepackage
:api:assemble
:api:cleanNode
:api:stage

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

And the Gradle is straight forward.

```
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "war"
apply plugin: "spring-boot"

task cleanNode {
    doLast {
        // clean up files we no longer need in the slug
        delete '../node_modules'
        delete '../html/bower_components'
    }
}

// used by Heroku
task stage {
    dependsOn cleanNode, assemble
}
```

Comment: Can you check that your `build.gradle` is checked into Git? Then can you check that you are pushing the correct branch by running `git push heroku HEAD:master`?

Comment: This is one hundred percent correct.

Comment: Does that mean the file *is* checked-in and you are deploying the correct branch, but you are still having the problem?

Comment: Right, sorry for not clarifying.  I `run bash`, `cat` the `build.gradle`.  Everything looks good.  I wonder if I have to use a wrapper.

Comment: It would be wise to use the wrapper. It will ensure you are running the same version of Gradle locally and on Heroku.

Comment: Adding the wrapper worked!  But, it pushed my slug size over the limit.  What now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113441/discussion-between-thomas-beauvais-and-codefinger).

Answer (score 1):

I had to use a Gradle Wrapper in order to use the same Gradle version.

Heroku was using Gradle 2.10 and I was using 2.13.  I am not sure what the difference was, but this is a good thing to do.

As @codefinger said, it's wise to use the same version.

As a bonus, I have added a bit to clean up the Heroku Slug reducing the size.

```
// used by Heroku
task stage {
    dependsOn assemble

    doLast {
        // https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-gradle-apps-on-heroku#using-grails-3
        // this still leaves around empty folders, but what are you going to do?
        delete fileTree(dir: "build", exclude: "libs")
        delete fileTree(dir: "build/libs", exclude: "*.jar")
    }
}
```